# 'poorly' organized csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that I have to do some data processing and it's a bit of a mess.  It's about 20 columns long, but there are multiple datasets that are concatenated in each column. see dummy file below

I'm trying to import each sub file into a separate pandas dataframe, but I'm not sure the best way to parse the csv other than manually hardcoding importing a certain length.  any suggestions? I guess if there is some way to find where the spaces are (I could loop through the entire file and find them, and then read each block, but that doesn't seem very efficient).  I have lots of csv files like this to read.

```py
import pandas as pd

nrows = 20
skiprows = 0 #but this only reads in the first block
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, nrows=nrows, skiprows=skiprows)
```

Below is a dummy example:

```
TIME,HDRA-1,HDRA-2,HDRA-3,HDRA-4
0.473934934,0.944026678,0.460177668,0.157028404,0.221362174
0.911384892,0.336694914,0.586014563,0.828339071,0.632790473
0.772652589,0.318146985,0.162987171,0.555896202,0.659099194
0.541382917,0.033706768,0.229596419,0.388057901,0.465507295
0.462815443,0.088206108,0.717132904,0.545779038,0.268174922
0.522861489,0.736462083,0.532785319,0.961993893,0.393424116
0.128671067,0.56740537,0.689995486,0.518493779,0.94916205
0.214026742,0.176948186,0.883636252,0.732258971,0.463732841
0.769415726,0.960761306,0.401863804,0.41823372,0.812081565
0.529750933,0.360314266,0.461615009,0.387516958,0.136616263

TIME,HDRB-1,HDRB-2,HDRB-3,HDRB-4
0.92264286,0.026312552,0.905839375,0.869477136,0.985560264
0.410573341,0.004825381,0.920616162,0.19473237,0.848603523
0.999293171,0.259955029,0.380094352,0.101050014,0.428047493
0.820216119,0.655118219,0.586754951,0.568492346,0.017038336
0.040384337,0.195101879,0.778631044,0.655215972,0.701596844
0.897559206,0.659759362,0.691643603,0.155601111,0.713735399
0.860188233,0.805013656,0.772153733,0.809025634,0.257632085
0.844167809,0.268060979,0.015993504,0.95131982,0.321210766
0.86288383,0.236599974,0.279435193,0.311005146,0.037592509
0.938348876,0.941851279,0.582434058,0.900348616,0.381844182
0.344351819,0.821571854,0.187962046,0.218234588,0.376122331
0.829766776,0.869014514,0.434165111,0.051749472,0.766748447
0.327865017,0.938176948,0.216764504,0.216666543,0.278110502
0.243953506,0.030809033,0.450110334,0.097976735,0.762393831
0.484856452,0.312943244,0.443236377,0.017201097,0.038786057
0.803696521,0.328088545,0.764850865,0.090543472,0.023363909

TIME,HDRB-1,HDRB-2,HDRB-3,HDRB-4
0.342418934,0.290979228,0.84201758,0.690964176,0.927385229
0.173485057,0.214049903,0.27438753,0.433904377,0.821778689
0.982816721,0.094490904,0.105895645,0.894103833,0.34362529
0.738593272,0.423470984,0.343551191,0.192169774,0.907698897
0.021809601,0.406001002,0.072701623,0.964640184,0.023427393
0.406226618,0.421944527,0.413150342,0.337243905,0.515996389
0.829989793,0.168974332,0.246064043,0.067662474,0.851182924
0.812736737,0.667154845,0.118274705,0.484017732,0.052666038
0.215947395,0.145078319,0.484063281,0.79414799,0.373845815
0.497877968,0.554808367,0.370429652,0.081553316,0.793608698
0.607612542,0.424703584,0.208995066,0.249033837,0.808169709
0.199613478,0.065853429,0.77236195,0.757789625,0.597225697
0.044167285,0.1024231,0.959682778,0.892311813,0.621810775
0.861175219,0.853442735,0.742542086,0.704287769,0.435969078
0.706544823,0.062501379,0.482065481,0.598698867,0.845585046
0.967217599,0.13127149,0.294860203,0.191045015,0.590202032
0.031666757,0.965674812,0.177792841,0.419935921,0.895265056

TIME,HDRB-1,HDRB-2,HDRB-3,HDRB-4
0.306849588,0.177454423,0.538670939,0.602747137,0.081221293
0.729747557,0.11762043,0.409064884,0.051577964,0.666653287
0.492543468,0.097222882,0.448642979,0.130965724,0.48613413
0.0802024,0.726352481,0.457476151,0.647556514,0.033820374
0.617976299,0.934428994,0.197735831,0.765364856,0.350880707
0.07660401,0.285816636,0.276995238,0.047003343,0.770284864
0.620820688,0.700434525,0.896417099,0.652364756,0.93838793
0.364233925,0.200229902,0.648342989,0.919306736,0.897029239
0.606100716,0.203585366,0.167232701,0.523079381,0.767224301
0.616600448,0.130377791,0.554714839,0.468486555,0.582775753
0.254480861,0.933534632,0.054558237,0.948978985,0.731855548
0.620161044,0.583061202,0.457991555,0.441254272,0.657127968
0.415874646,0.408141761,0.843133575,0.40991199,0.540792744
0.254903429,0.655739954,0.977873649,0.210656057,0.072451639
0.473680525,0.298845701,0.144989283,0.998560665,0.223980961
0.30605008,0.837920854,0.450681322,0.887787908,0.793229776
0.584644405,0.423279153,0.444505314,0.686058204,0.041154856
```

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I unfortunately cannot post the datafile, I know it's a bit confusing without the datafile.  I could make up something that mirrors my data, would that help?

Comment: If you want to help others help you, you're better off providing dummy data, the desired result, and the algorithm you've tried but failed.

Comment: It's not clear whether the random length is horizontal or vertical. In any case provide a complete dummy example without "..." or text description, and the matching expected output. If there are really random lined in between your lines of data, how do you know which ones are the lovers to keep or drop?

Comment: Sorry for the bad questions, hopefully my edits will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


data ="""
TIME,HDRA-1,HDRA-2,HDRA-3,HDRA-4 
0.473934934,0.944026678,0.460177668,0.157028404,0.221362174
0.911384892,0.336694914,0.586014563,0.828339071,0.632790473 
0.772652589,0.318146985,0.162987171,0.555896202,0.659099194 
0.541382917,0.033706768,0.229596419,0.388057901,0.465507295 
0.462815443,0.088206108,0.717132904,0.545779038,0.268174922 
0.522861489,0.736462083,0.532785319,0.961993893,0.393424116 

TIME,HDRB-1,HDRB-2,HDRB-3,HDRB-4 
0.92264286,0.026312552,0.905839375,0.869477136,0.985560264 
0.410573341,0.004825381,0.920616162,0.19473237,0.848603523 
0.999293171,0.259955029,0.380094352,0.101050014,0.428047493 
0.820216119,0.655118219,0.586754951,0.568492346,0.017038336 
0.040384337,0.195101879,0.778631044,0.655215972,0.701596844 

TIME,HDRB-1,HDRB-2,HDRB-3,HDRB-4 
0.342418934,0.290979228,0.84201758,0.690964176,0.927385229 
0.173485057,0.214049903,0.27438753,0.433904377,0.821778689 
0.982816721,0.094490904,0.105895645,0.894103833,0.34362529 
0.738593272,0.423470984,0.343551191,0.192169774,0.907698897 
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None)

start_marker = 'TIME'
grouper = (df.iloc[:, 0] == start_marker).cumsum()
groups = df.groupby(grouper)

frames = [gr.T.set_index(gr.index[0]).T for _, gr in groups]
```

[image: frames]

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with the StringIO module. Will look into that.  I think I understand everything except the last line 'frames = [gr.T.set_index(gr.index[0]).T for _, gr in groups]'

Comment: one other quick question, the example had the data as a large string object.  My actual example it's a CSV file.  I can manually read all of the rows into a string, but there is probably an simpler way correct?

Comment: @user14396455 No need to reed about `StringIO`, that's just a substitution for the real file. The last line could be like this `[g for i, g in groups]` which means _collect the groups into a list_. `T` - transpose, or swap axes. `T.set_index(...).T` - make one of the rows to be a column titles. Read the file as usual `df = pd.read_csv(your_file_name)`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it working.  appreciate your help!